# Estimating the amplitude of a particular frequency

Tags: frequency-spectrum, frequency, estimation, dsp-core, amplitude

I am relatively new to DSP and have been reading a lot on the internet. I have a couple of questions.

I have a signal in the form of a function 
$$
f(x) = A_0 + A_1 \cos(\omega_1 x) + A_2 \cos(\omega_2 x)+...+ A_n \cos(\omega_n x). 
$$
I have $f(x)$ and I know the minimum and maximum frequencies. $f(x)$ can have really high frequencies.

a) I need to find the amplitude $A_p$ of a particular frequency $\omega_p$ in $f(x)$. One way to do this is, I could get sample points from $f(x)$ sampling at greater than Nyquist rate and do an FFT and find the amplitude. But if $f(x)$ has really high frequencies, the sampling would take most of the time. If i am interested only in estimating the amplitude $A_p$, is there another way, a faster way, of doing this. In the best case, I would like to estimate $A_p$ to within 0.5 of its actual value.

b)If I want $A_0$, the DC component, I can compute the average of $f(x)$ but with high frequencies in $f(x)$ that would mean high sampling rates. Any other faster way of doing this?

c)The FFT takes $O(n\log(n))$ if $n$ is the size of the input and returns the magnitudes for $n$ different frequencies. If we are only interested in one particular frequency we should be able to alter the source code so that it would take only $O(\log(n))$, right?

Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 6):

The usual way to estimate the amplitude of a particular frequency is to use the [Goertzel algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm)  There is a [good write-up by Rick Lyons here.](http://www.embedded.com/design/real-world-applications/4401754/Single-tone-detection-with-the-Goertzel-algorithm)

Even though Rick's writeup is about single tone detection, it can be applied when multiple tones are present, too.

Comment: Unless they are close relative to the observation time. Then the estimation isn't good.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have a look at [Goertzels Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm).

Comment: Beat me to it! :-) +1

Comment: OP states that he only knows the bounds of the frequencies w1...wn, not the individual values. Goertzel requires knowing the frequency wp. Is it known?

Comment: @John : Good point! I missed that piece. :-(

Comment: yes, i know w1, wp and wn